# he method executequery() cannot take arguments on callablestatement

Tags: java, sql-server, swing

I'm writing a program in which I want to delete selected rows from jtable which must necessarily be done through stored procedure using java .
Ι create the following stored procedure (mssql):

```
USE [Lab]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_member_delete]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @members_id int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
delete from members where Members_id=@members_id
END
```

And the java code to call the procedure

```
 private void cmdDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        if(!jTable2.getSelectionModel().isSelectionEmpty()){
        int click=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"Are you sure","Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(click==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)

        try {
       Connect c=new Connect();
       Connection con=c.start();
       //Statement ps=con.createStatement();
       CallableStatement ps=con.prepareCall ("{call usp_member_delete(?,?)}");
       int index []=jTable2.getSelectedRows();
       for (int i=0;i<index.length;i++)
       {String id=""+jTable2.getValueAt(index[i], 0);
       //ps.execute("delete from members where member_id="+id);
       ps.executeUpdate(id);
         c.stop();
       }

     DefaultTableModel mod=(DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
     for (int i=0;i<index.length;i++)
     mod.removeRow(index [i]-i);

     }catch (Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);}
    }                                         
    }
```

Iam getting error the method executequery() cannot take arguments on preparestatement or callablestatement.Could you please advice?
Thank you in advance for your answer
Elpiniki

Comment: You might look at the java documentation for passing values to a prepared statement. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Hi ,Thank you for your answer.Iam using CallableStatement and I have read oracle and other documentations about it.

Comment: You obviously have not read the documentation. The link I shared explains how to do this very clearly. Look at the section "Supplying Values for PreparedStatement Parameters"

Comment: Hi ,I've read it and I've already created connections (as examples following codes)

Comment: In your "answer" below you demonstrate setting the parameter values. Why are you doing it completely differently above? Just use ps.setString for your delete. The same process just a different procedure.

Comment: it makes it difficult for me that ι get the id using getSelectedRows while in the latter example I get it  for identity row.

Comment: To understand how this works take the loop out for now. Figure out how to delete a single one. Simple enough? Then put that logic inside your loop.

Comment: Whether I have a row or many my problem is the same in which way the moment I choose a row i will get rows id (the id of the selected row which is parameter on stored procedure) in order to make the stored procedure works for me.

Comment: Well...in your code you have two parameters to the procedure, in your procedure code there is only one. And in your code above you are trying something completely different. You need to use the setString method just like you did in your answer below. I am truly horrified that you can't see an example of your own code and adapt it for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've read it and I've already created connections for other purposes like insert.T (as examples following codes)    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
 String name=jTextField2.getText();
 String email =jTextField3.getText();
 String site=jTextField4.getText();
 String cv=jTextArea2.getText();
 String category =jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
  try
{
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

     try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\\ELPINIKI-TOSH\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=Lab","sa","fir3w@ll")) {

         CallableStatement ps=con.prepareCall ("{call usp_member_insert(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
         ps.registerOutParameter("Members_id", java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
         ps.setString(2,name);
         ps.setString(3,email);
         ps.setString(4,site);
         ps.setString(5,cv);
         ps.setString(6,category);
         ps.registerOutParameter("MemberCategory_id",java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

         int x=0; x=ps.executeUpdate();
         if (x!=0);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data inserted");

         jTextField2.setText("");
         jTextField3.setText("");
         jTextField4.setText("");
         jComboBox2.setSelectedIndex(0);
         jTextArea2.setText("");
       con.close();  
     }
}catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

The problem is with the previous code i attached.Iam using row select and i want to delete the row using the procedure.
Thank you